# Using Linq to select distinct UserID and longer entry

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I currently get two DataTables getting populated from two sets of data where a user can live twice. Example:

Table 1:

```
UserID | DisplayName | FirstName | LastName
  1       John Doe      John        Doe
  2       Jane Doe      Jane        Doe
```

Table 2:

```
UserID | DisplayName
  1       John Doe
  2       Jane Doe
  3      Sally Brown
```

My hope is to merge the two tables, based on a unique UserID, and preserve the data columns of the largest batch. So I would keep the columns `UserID`, `DisplayName`,`FistName`, and `LastName` when merging.

```
UserID | DisplayName | FirstName | LastName
  1       John Doe      John        Doe
  2       Jane Doe      Jane        Doe
  3      Sally Brown
```

I have tried using `table.DefaultView.ToTable(true, {list of columns})` however this will not correctly put in distinct data in the rows because it things UserID  1 and 2 from table 2 is unique from that in table 1.

It looks like the linq-ing with VB is weird and I can't seem to preserve the columns. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would merge the datatables and then take the rows distinct by `UserID`:

```
table1.Merge(table2)

Dim dtnew = table1.AsEnumerable() _
    .GroupBy(Function(d) d.Field(Of Integer)("UserID")) _
    .Select(Function(g) g.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable()
```